# Sumar campos dinámicos jQuery

Tags: jquery

Estoy haciendo un formulario para calcular el costo de un producto, tengo hecho el costo del flete según el peso. Ahora, como puedo tomar el valor del peso para sumarlo al precio del producto.

Por ej.

```
$("#peso").keyup(function(){

   value = $(this).val();

   if(value > 2){
     flete = 4.95;
    }
   else{
     flete = 8.95;
   }
    $("#flete").val(flete.toFixed(2));
});
```

Necesito tomar el valor del flete para sumarlo al precio del producto, y mostrar en un div el precio final.

Me funciona con la primera respuesta pero se me había olvidado otro dato, tengo otra función que verifica si se necesitara el manejo de la empresa.

```
$(".manejo" ).change(function() {
     var costo = $("input[name=resp]:checked" ).val();

          if(costo == "si"){
              costoManejo = 5.35;
            }
           else{
               costoManejo = 0;
            }

            $("#costo-manejo").val(costoManejo.toFixed(2));

});
```

Mi duda ahí es mas con el ámbito de las variables porque necesito sumar el precio del producto + flete + manejo.

Comment: Puedes agregar como tienes listados los productos? Para que sepamos de donde sacar el valor de ese producto? A tiempo real te refieres a?

Answer (score 1):

Ojala te sirva esta solución:

```js
$("#txtPeso").keyup(function(){
  $("#txtFlete").val($(this).val() > 2 ? 4.95 : 8.95 );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Peso: <input type="text" id="txtPeso"></input>

Flete: <input type="text" id="txtFlete"></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Pues según entiendo quedaría algo así:

```
$("#peso").keyup(function(){

   value = $(this).val();

   if(value > 2){
     flete = 4.95;
    }
   else{
     flete = 8.95;
   }
    $("#flete").val(flete.toFixed(2));

    var precio = $("#precio").val();
    var preciofinal = precio + flete;
    $("#preciofinal").val(preciofinal.toFixed(2));
});
```

Comment: Agregalo al editor para poder verlo en funcionamiento de una vez